# Data organisation in R: vectors of differing lengths as a single object

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to plot multiple overlaying density plots for two vectors on the same figure. As far as I know, I'm not able to do so unless they are in the same object.

In order to plot the data, I need to have a data.frame() with two columns; one for the value, and one to specify which vector each value belongs to.

My first vector contains 400 data. The second contains 1200. My current (somewhat inelegant) solution involves concatenating the two vectors into a new data.frame vector, and adding a second vector to the data.frame which contains 400 'a's and 1200 'b's, to indicate which vector the original data came from. This only works because I know how many data there were in each original vector.

Surely there must be a more efficient way to do this?

Let's say my original data are from `dframe1$vector` and `dframe2$vector`. I'm looking to create a new object called `dframe3` which contains the columns `$value` and `$original_vector_number`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to solve a problem you don't need to solve. You don't need to have them in the same object to plot their densities. Just use `lines`.

```
x <- rnorm(400,0,1)
y <- rnorm(1200,2,2)
plot(density(x))
lines(density(y))
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I'm using ggplot2; it turns out that the way to do this is to simply *not* specify a data set when making the initial call to ggplot2.

Answer (score -1):

Use `library(reshape)` and `melt` if you don't want to do this by hand:

```
library(reshape)
dframe <- data.frame(a = rnorm(400,1,1),b = rnorm(1200,1.2,2))
df.m <- melt(dframe)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.m,aes(x = value,color = variable)) + geom_density()
```

> Note that this will not truly provide the correct answer as putting the data frames together does expand the smaller of the two to fit the number of rows. The correct way to do this and plot in ggplot is the following:

By hand:

```
vecA <- data.frame(rnorm(400,1,1),'a')
vecB <- data.frame(rnorm(1200,1.2,2),'b')
names(vecA) <- c('value','name')
names(vecB) <- c('value','name')
dtf <- rbind(vecA,vecB)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dtf,aes(x=value,color=name))+geom_density()
```

Comment: This uses vector recycling and thus won't give the right answer. For example, try `dframe <- data.frame(a = rnorm(400,1,1),b = rnorm(1201,1.2,2))`.

Comment: True, the first option does not work if the vectors are not multiple sizes of each other, but the second does, if you want to use ggplot to plot the two together.